# Using HtmlDecode without "script" tag in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core and want to display html string via razor syntax.

I've tried:

```
@{
    string content = Model.Content.Replace("<script>", "&lt;script&gt;")
                                  .Replace("</script>", "&lt;/script&gt;");
}
@Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(content))
```

with the input:

```
<b>foo</b><script>alert('bar')</script>
```

But `alert` function in the script tag was still called. How to avoid it (only script tag)?

Answer (score 0):

you can used `convert.ToString` function to convert you `html.raw` data to `string` format

like this

```
@Convert.ToString(@Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(content)))
```

so that alert function not called.

Comment: Only script tag, please!

Comment: This won't work, as it will simply HTML encode everything again. It's an exercise in futility, since that's what you already had to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the replacements *after* you decode. As it stands, you're just decoding your HTML entity replacements, which then just makes them normal tags again.

```
@{
    var content = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content);
    var replacedContent = content.Replace("<script>", "&lt;script&gt;")
                                 .Replace("</script>", "&lt;/script&gt;");
}
@Html.Raw(replacedContent)
```

For what it's worth, I don't think you actually need to even decode at all here, though. It's not really doing anything. In other words, this is functionally equivalent:

```
@{
    var content = Model.Content.Replace("<script>", "&lt;script&gt;")
                               .Replace("</script>", "&lt;/script&gt;");
}
@Html.Raw(content)
```

If the scripts tags were already encoded, they'll remain that way when you dump them via `Html.Raw`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It displays everything as normal string. So, I think about this way: split the content to multiple parts based on `<script>` and `</script>` indexes. Then, merging them. But, it looks like too complex.

Comment: If `Model.Content` is *already* encoded (such that all the tags are encoded), then you would need to decode first. Either way, the point is that your should do your replacement on the already fully-decoded HTML, not *before*.

Comment: Ya. But not at all, except `script` tag.